# How do I authenticate a user to my API with firebase without using a firebase login or password?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

While making an API in Express Js for my project I ran into a problem because I do not want any user to get any data from the database I have to somehow authenticate them with some kind of token. After doing probably pretty poor research online I didn't find anything that could fit because I want the token to be used only by one user and stay like it is forever or until a user deletes its account, is there any way to safely let the user access his data from database without worries of any other user accessing the same probably private data like direct messages?

Comment: " have to somehow authenticate them with some kind of token. " Why don't you wan to use a token generated by Firebase? Which other authentication system do you foresee for generating this token?

Comment: Right now i feel kind of stupid but what token are you talking about?

Comment: "I want the token to be used only by one user and stay like it is forever" The token you mention in your question

Answer (score 0):

> I want the token to be used only by one user and stay like it is forever or until a user deletes their account.

I think you're looking for [Firebase Anonymous Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth).

This means that an anonymous account will be available until the user explicitly signs out or explicitly deletes the account.

> Is there any way to safely let the user access his data from the database without worries of any other user accessing the same probably private data like direct messages?

Yes, once you implement Firebase Anonymous Authentication, then you can then secure user data using [Security Rules for Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) or, [Security Rules for the Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security).

Comment: Hey Cartoon. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for your use case?